# How to use column name in render function using datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a question that I think has a easy answer but I cant find how to do it on the forum..

The following code is used to send info to a ajax script when checkbox is checked or unchecked. It now only sent the the data from kwartaal_id to the script. But I also need the column name to be send to the ajax script since i use more of these checkboxes on one page and I need to know which one is triggered. So I need the column name to be posted the same as I do with the row.kwartaal_id. How do I do that? I imagine it would be like this..

```
"columns": [
                 
                {data: 'kwartaal_klant',
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return ''+data+'';
                } } , 
                    {data: 'kwartaal_notes',
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return ''+data+'';
                } } ,    
                {data: 'kwartaal_1'},
                {data: 'kwartaal_2'},
                {data: 'kwartaal_3'},
                {data: 'kwartaal_4'},
                {data: 'kwartaal_user',
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return ''+data+'';
                } } , 
                 ],
```

Before:

```
{targets: [2,3,4,5],
      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        if ( type !== 'display' )
         
          return ""; //Empty cell content
        else {             //if column data is 1 then set attr to checked, use row id as input id (plus prefix)
          return '<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' value="' + row.kwartaal_id + '" class="active" /><div class="slider round"><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span></div></label>';
        }
 
        return data;
   },
```

After: (added the ''name'' attribute)

```
{targets: [2,3,4,5],
     render: function ( data, type, row ) {
       if ( type !== 'display' )
        
         return ""; //Empty cell content
       else {             //if column data is 1 then set attr to checked, use row id as input id (plus prefix)
         return '<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' value="' + row.kwartaal_id + '"
         class="active" name="' + columnName + '" /><div class="slider round"><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span></div></label>';
       }
 
       return data;
  },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the column name" and that `columnName` variable here? Do you mean the column heading displayed to the user in the DataTable? Do you mean the DataTables [`columns.name`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) option (and if so, are you actually setting that anywhere)? Or do you mean something else? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I mean the colomn name presented in here: {data: 'kwartaal_1'}, I need to post the name of of the data. so kwartaal_1 when a cell in that colomn is selected, kwartaal_2 if that is selected. Etc.

Comment: OK - got it - thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `meta` object in the column renderer to access a column's `data` value:

```
meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].mData
```

This accesses the DataTables `settings` object which contains an array of column `data` values. You can get the relevant entry in that array by using `meta.col` which is the current column's index.

Here is an example:

```js
var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Zürich",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "57",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];
 
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  lengthMenu: [ [2, -1] , [2, "All"] ],
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "ID", data: "id" },
    { title: "Name", data: "name" },
    { title: "Office", data: "office" },
    { title: "Position", data: "position" },
    { 
      title: "Start date", 
      data: "start_date",
      render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          //console.log( meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].mData );
          return meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].mData;
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    },
    { title: "Extn.", data: "extn" },
    { title: "Salary", data: "salary" }
  ]

} );


} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The demo simply prints the `data` value in the Start Date column. You can obviously use that value in your `name="' + columnName + '"` code instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not know if this was what you intended. But I simply used your suggestion like this ` {targets: [2,3,4,5], 
  render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
    
         if ( type !== 'display' )
   
           return ""; 
         else {     
  return '<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' value="' + row.kwartaal_id + '" class="active" name="' + meta.settings.aoColumns[meta.col].mData + '" /><div class="slider round"><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span></div></label>';
   `